# Count Arraylist из другого класса

Tags: классы, c#

Всем доброго времени суток!
В программе на С# имеется 2 класса. В одном из них arraylist. В другом классе нужно знать Count от этого arraylist. Как это можно сделать?
Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Вывести Count от ArrayList в свойство того класса, который его содержит.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю поможет модификатор доступа [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7c5ka91b.aspx).